# Inno Setup does not (always) compile the latest version of my program

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, inno-setup

I have used Inno Setup a lot recently to generate an installer for my .NET Winforms app. I found that many times the wrong (older) version of my program was installed. To verify this, I have a caption on my Form that shows the version (hard-coded). 
Even after uninstalling the previous version, re-building my app and verifying by starting the .exe in my debug folder first - this shows the correct version. But when I run the (unchanged) setup script again, it starts and older version of my program after setup is finished. BTW, I install in the same directory (overwriting). Last time I did this twice and then it came up with the right version. Has anyone seen this before?

I have included the .iss file contents. NOTE: I did not say it does not work, it does not work most of the time.

```
 ; Script generated by the Inno Setup Script Wizard.
; SEE THE DOCUMENTATION FOR DETAILS ON CREATING INNO SETUP SCRIPT FILES!

#define MyAppName "panelsTest"
#define MyAppVersion "1.0"
#define MyAppPublisher "My Company, Inc."
#define MyAppURL "http://www.example.com/"
#define MyAppExeName "panelsTest.exe"

[Setup]
; NOTE: The value of AppId uniquely identifies this application. Do not use the same AppId value in installers for other applications.
; (To generate a new GUID, click Tools | Generate GUID inside the IDE.)
AppId={{51065F75-A2F7-4C12-A915-68C1E8F0395B}
AppName={#MyAppName}
AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}
;AppVerName={#MyAppName} {#MyAppVersion}
AppPublisher={#MyAppPublisher}
AppPublisherURL={#MyAppURL}
AppSupportURL={#MyAppURL}
AppUpdatesURL={#MyAppURL}
DefaultDirName=c:\panelsTest\{#MyAppName}
DisableProgramGroupPage=yes
; Uncomment the following line to run in non administrative install mode (install for current user only.)
;PrivilegesRequired=lowest
OutputBaseFilename=mysetup
Compression=lzma
SolidCompression=yes
WizardStyle=modern
SetupLogging=yes

[Languages]
Name: "english"; MessagesFile: "compiler:Default.isl"

[Tasks]
Name: "desktopicon"; Description: "{cm:CreateDesktopIcon}"; GroupDescription: "{cm:AdditionalIcons}"; Flags: unchecked

[Files]
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\panelsTest.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\columns.json"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Data.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Data.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Images.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Office.v19.2.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Office.v19.2.Core.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Pdf.v19.2.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Pdf.v19.2.Core.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Printing.v19.2.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Printing.v19.2.Core.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.RichEdit.v19.2.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.RichEdit.v19.2.Core.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Sparkline.v19.2.Core.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Sparkline.v19.2.Core.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Utils.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.Utils.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraBars.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraBars.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraEditors.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraGrid.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraGrid.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraLayout.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraLayout.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraPrinting.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v19.2.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\DevExpress.XtraTreeList.v19.2.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\EMO-72-07-200.ubo"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\fileLoc.bin"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\fileLocs.json"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\Fizzler.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\materials.json"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\Newtonsoft.Json.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\panelsTest.exe"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\panelsTest.exe.config"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\panelsTest.pdb"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\Svg.dll"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
Source: "C:\Users\Gebruiker\Documents\batchunfolder\WindowsFormsApp1\panelsTest\bin\Debug\Svg.xml"; DestDir: "{app}"; Flags: ignoreversion
; NOTE: Don't use "Flags: ignoreversion" on any shared system files

[Icons]
Name: "{autoprograms}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"
Name: "{autodesktop}\{#MyAppName}"; Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Tasks: desktopicon

[Run]
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; Flags: nowait postinstall skipifsilent
```

Comment: Maybe you need to define: `#define MyAppVersion GetFileVersion("..\PathTo\Your.exe")` then in the `[SetUp]` section, add `AppVersion={#MyAppVersion}`. Also check the other properties like: `VersionInfoVersion` and `VersionInfoProductVersion`.

Comment: Kind of hard to say why your install script isn't working correctly when building your install when you don't show us the install script. An install script for Inno Setup is just like the source code for an application. When you ask a questoin about C# code here, you're required to provide a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. Inno Setup code is the same; if you want us to help you debug issues with it, you need to include the .iss file here in the question as well.